# WPF Web Browser Control with Custom Scrollbar

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollbar, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to make a custom scroll bar for `Web browser Control`.

I used a `Scroll Bar Control` for this,so i attached `Scroll Bar Control` to `Web browser Control`
use following code:

```
        Doc = (mshtml.HTMLDocument)browser.Document;
        Doc.parentWindow.document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
        mshtml.IHTMLElement2 ScrolablePlace= (mshtml.IHTMLElement2)Doc.getElementById("ScrolablePlace");
        ScrollBar.ViewportSize = browser.ActualHeight;
        ScrollBar.Maximum = ScrolablePlace.scrollHeight;
```

and while scroling scrolbar:

```
 private void ScrollBar_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Doc != null)
            {
                Doc.parentWindow.scroll(0, (int)e.NewValue);
            }
        }
```

this is work,but `ScrollBar.Maximum` value is always larger than scroll bar place.dose `ScrollBar.ViewportSize`  and `ScrollBar.Maximum` 
set correctly?

I Hope i could explain my problem correctly with this image:

[image]

Comment: I've the same problem, I need to customize the scrollbars of the WPF webbrowser and based on your question and answer I could not solve my problem. could you explain please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research, I've found that a scroll bar `maximum` property must calculate from this formula :

```
scrolbar.maximum=(maxsize-scrolbar.ViewportSize)+scrolbar.smallchanges
```

so i simply do this and it work fine:

```
   ScrollBar.Maximum = ScrolablePlace.scrollHeight- browser.ActualHeight+ScrollBar.SmallChange;
```